# Using same menu on multiple pages ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I'm trying to make one menu and using it on every web page I have instead of copying the same code in every file. This way I can change the menu in one file instead of 5.
I'm using ASP.NET Web Forms application (aspx-files).
I've tried googling it but the only result I get is PHP related, isn't there a way to do it with aspx/html files?

Comment: You can create ascx Contol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for master pages: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create your menu in Web user control and then include it where ever you need

Answer (score 0):

This link can show you how to add Menu bar in Master page, If Menu bar is in master page then you don't need to change the code in every page.
[Master Page with Menu bar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333650/Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-Master-Pages-in-ASP-NET)